# basis of direct sum of matrix algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

It is a very basic question. But I am not able to find the answer. What is a basis for $M_1(\mathbb{C})\oplus M_1(\mathbb{C})\oplus M_2(\mathbb{C})$ interms of the basis of each terms. We have the group structure $\mathbb{C}S_3$ is as above. How can I map the basis elements $S_3$ from one side to the other side so that it gives an algebra isomorphism?